# jsp failed to embed applet from jar, class-file not found

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I try to embed an applet into my Applet.jsp via jsp:plugin.
When I call the jsp through tomcat, the applet throws a "ClassNotFoundException".

So far I figured out, that the jar-file could be found and even downloaded, when I entered the classpath into url. In my tomcat-logs I see, that the test.jar is found, but not the MyClass.class in it.

My project-structure:

```
webapp
- applets
  - test.jar
- WEB-INF
  - templates
    - Applet.jsp
  - web.xml
```

The jar file only contains MyClass.class.

**Applet.jsp**

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" /webapp/applets/test.jar" code="MyClass.class" width="300" height="300"></jsp:plugin>
```

**Tomcat log**

```
"POST /webapp/servlet/applet HTTP/1.1" 200 
"GET /webapp/applets/test.jar/MyClass.class HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I also tried

**Applet.jsp**

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" archive="/webapp/applets/test.jar" code="MyClass" width="300" height="300"></jsp:plugin>
```

and several variations, but no luck.

**Tomcat log**

```
"POST /webapp/servlet/applet HTTP/1.1" 200 
"GET /webapp/applets/test.jar HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /webapp/servlet/MyClass.class HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Versions are java 1.7, tomcat 7

Why isn't MyClass.class found in the test.jar?

**EDIT**

I figured out, that is has to do with the jsp or so.
My html with embeded applet-jar works, the jsp still fails.

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>
  <object codetype="application/java-vm" width="300" height="300" archive="test.jar" classid="java:MyClass.class"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody some ideas about why jsp won't cooperate?
And at least I would love to use jsp:plugin

Comment: Isn't `/webapp` effectively `/` to the public?

Comment: Also, I thought all your hosted/shared stuff had to be under WEB-INF?

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but I've read, that it is a frequent error to put files there, when you want to read them afterwards. Anyway I'll give it a try.  ;)

Comment: As I thought. Under the WEB-INF directory I even can not access the jar via url.

Comment: By now I "solved" it by loading the jar from a apache-server. But as long as this is no real solution, I won't add it as answer.